# Polymer via javascript paper button

Tags: javascript, polymer, paper-elements

how to implement a polymer paper button via javascript? 
I'm trying something like this.

```
var newPaperButtonElement = document.createElement('paper-button');
    newPaperButtonElement.setAttribute('class','btn');
    newPaperButtonElement.setAttribute('on-tap','{{ test}}');


var newCoreIconElement = document.createElement('core-icon');
    newCoreIconElement.setAttribute('icon','remove-circle');
    newCoreIconElement.setAttribute('class','icon');
    newCoreIconElement.setAttribute('style', 'color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.42);')

    newPaperButtonElement.appendChild(newCoreIconElement);
```

But my function gets never called? Nothing happends. Using Polymer 0.5 atm...

Comment: Your are appending 'newCoreIconElement' to 'newPaperButtonElement'(as a child) but, are you appending 'newPaperButtonElement' to the document?

Comment: Yes sure. I see the button. But nothing happends when I click on it

Comment: M8, why on earth are you using Polymer 0.5, when there's a 1.0.x version out, which basically overhauled the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add binding imperatively. If you create the element imperatively you have to add/remove event handler imperatively

```
newPaperButtonElement.addEventListener('tap', this.test);
```

`test` might need to look differently depending on where the function is (your question doesn't provide context).

I hope I got the syntax right, I don't use JS (only Dart).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When a `tap` event is fired by the `newPaperButtonElement` the registered event handler (function) should be called.

Comment: Okay, now it work's with this newPaperButtonElement.addEventListener('tap', test); I need just change test with this.test. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear you figured it out and thanks for the feedback!